# Configure Litespeed to serve as a frontend proxy for chatwoot or any docker

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, litespeed, chatwoot

My docker chatwoot is now fully activated, but I don't know how to convert my litespeed(As part of my Cpanel installation, I installed Litespeed) to a frontend proxy like the setting below belongs to Nginx.

```
 server {
  server_name <yourdomain.com>;

  # Point upstream to Chatwoot App Server
  set $upstream 127.0.0.1:3000;

  # Nginx strips out underscore in headers by default
  # Chatwoot relies on underscore in headers for API
  # Make sure that the config is set to on.
  underscores_in_headers on;
  location /.well-known {
    alias /var/www/ssl-proof/chatwoot/.well-known;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on; # Optional

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection “”;
    proxy_buffering off;

    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
  listen 80;
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: Did you install **lightspeed** or **litespeed**?

Comment: I greatly appreciate you pointing out the first typo in litespeed

Comment: have you checked this doc ?  https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:proxy:lsws-as-a-proxy-rewrite

Comment: Not work very well

Answer (score 0):

Testing led me to the answer.
A .htaccess file with this content can be created in the public_html of that domain or subdomain if someone has this problem.

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit


#ProxyPreserveHost On
#ProxyPassMatch  "/(.*)$"  "http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```